# Can't call custom validation in MY_Form_validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I've created a custom validation class in code igniter.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function __construct($rules = array()) {
        parent::__construct($rules);
    }

    public function required_fr($str) {
        var_dump('test');
        if (!is_array($str)) {
            return (trim($str) == '') ? FALSE : TRUE;
        } else {
            return (!empty($str));
        }
    }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class Ticket extends CI_Controller { 

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><a aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</a>', '</div>');            
    }

    public function new_ticket() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'categorie', 'required_fr');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't fill in the field 'category', the validate 'required_fr' isn't getting called. I never get the message 'test' from the var_dump on my screen.

If I put 'required' instead of 'required_fr', I get the right message bound to required in my page. If I put required_fr, I don't get any message at all.

I also tried adding callback_ in the set_rules function of the form validation, but that doesn't seem to work either.

If I put a var_dump in the constructor of the MY_Form_validation class, I see it popping up on my page, so the custom validation class gets loaded.

What am I missing?

Comment: If I put the function from my custom validator into my controller, and call it with 'callback_required_fr', it works like a charm. But I want to put it in an external class, so I can inherit into other controllers as well.

Comment: For custom validator the better solution is to create a validation helper instead of library in application/helper folder. You can call the validation function without using "callback_"

Answer (score 0):

**class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation**

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{    
    function __construct($config = array()){
        parent::__construct($config);
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->_config_rules = $config;
    }   
    public function required_fr($str) {
        if (!is_array($str)) {
            if(!empty(trim($str))){ return true;
            }else{
                $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('required_fr', 'String value is empty');
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if(array_filter($str){ return true;
            }else{
                $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('required_fr', 'Array value is empty');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**class Ticket extends CI_Controller**

```
class Ticket extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><a aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</a>', '</div>');            
    }
    public function new_ticket() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'categorie', 'trim|required_fr');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
            // success
            _e($this->input->post());
        }else{
            _e($this->form_validation->error_array());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested, but it is not working. I still don't get the message related with 'required_fr'. If I change 'required_fr' with 'required' I do get the message related to 'required'. There is still something wrong with calling the custom validation function, but I have absolutely no idea what.

Comment: @Walle, now check my updated answer. previously we didn't assign error message for `required_fr`, check now, i hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of $str use input post

Filename application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

```
<?php

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

protected $CI;

public function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}

public function required_fr() {
    if (!is_array($this->CI->input->post('your_input_name'))) {

        if (trim($this->CI->input->post('your_input_name')) == '') {
            $this->set_message('required_fr','some message');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```